# Is there any limit on number of tags we can create in a single database in CnosDB?

Tags: database, opentsdb, cnosdb

OpenTSDB by default support up to 8 tags in a database (see [here](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing/index.html)) and you can modify this in configuration. Since CnosDB is adopting similar tag-set model, is there any limit on the number of tags we can create in a single database here then?

I assume the limitation (if exists) is there to avoid the high series cardinality, which could lead to OOM, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, there are some settings about tags and series in config file.

- `max-series-per-database = 1000000`
  The maximum number of series allowed per database before writes are dropped. The default setting is 1000000. Change the setting to 0 to allow an unlimited number of series per database.

If a point causes the number of series in a database to exceed max-series-per-database, CnosDB will not write the point, and it returns error.

- `max-values-per-tag = 100000`
  The maximum number of tag values allowed per tag key. The default value is 100000. Change the setting to 0 to allow an unlimited number of tag values per tag key. If a tag value causes the number of tag values of a tag key to exceed max-values-per-tag, then CnosDB will not write the point, and it returns a partial write error.

Any existing tag keys with tag values that exceed max-values-per-tag will continue to accept writes, but writes that create a new tag value will fail.

The more tags you have, the more series you have. By default, you can't create unlimited series in a CnosDB instance. If you want to write more series and tags to a CnosDB instance, you can edit the config file and use the command `cnosdb --config /config/file/directory` to import the config file. Then restart the CnosDB instance, the new config file will go into effect.

Click [here](https://www.cnosdb.com/content/cnosdb/latest/managerment/configuration.html) for more information about the config file of CnosDB.

Comment: So there is no limit on number of tags if you open up the config and have enough resources, right;)

Comment: Yeah. You're right.